# How to ensure callback order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Say, I have a RoR application with multiple plugins. Each of these plugins implements an after_save callback on a model. I need to create one more plugin with two more callbacks, say, `start` and `finish`. How do I ensure the following order of callback execution?

- MyPlugin.start
- OtherPlugin_1.after_save_1
- OtherPlugin_1.after_save_X
- OtherPlugin_X.after_save_1
- ...
- MyPlugin.finish

I.e. my callback should be called before any other after_save and immediately after all other after_save callbacks have finished execution.

Comment: Are you limited to safe? Couldn't you finish after commit?

Comment: @Leito, this is an option for now as there seem to be no after_commit callbacks so far, but I'd like to resort to it only if there is no more general solution.

Comment: I would advise creating one after_save on the model and then in that method, calling each of the plugin functions in the order you desire.  Having the plugin export after_save callbacks and not regular model methods is unnecessary.

Comment: @maxpleaner, I can't change the model, but I may create a 'meta-plugin' calling all the other methods in a single after_save callback. Guess this may work. I suppose I might even collect these methods automatically based on some method naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by using `prepend: true` for MyPlugin.start, as follows:

```
after_save :start, prepend: true
```

Assuming, that no other plugin uses `:prepend`.

Regarding MyPlugin.finish: the only option (as far as I know) is to make sure, that the plugin is executed last (e.g., by naming it `zzz`).